# Adding permission for ml-data folder using ml-gradle

Tags: gradle, marklogic-10, ml-gradle, gradle.properties

I'm using ml-gradle plugin to deploy the data and modules to a ML10 database. I have used **mlModulePermissions** property to set permissions for modules.

Is there a similar property to set permissions for the files loaded from ml-data directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an equivalent property for data permissions:

> **mlDataPermissions**  Comma-delimited list of permissions (role1,capability1,role2,capability2,etc) assigned to each document. No default value (which typically means you'll get rest-reader/read and rest-writer/update as permissions on each document).

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-app-deployer/wiki/Loading-data

Comment: yeah, got it from ml-gradle related document ,Thanks!